# Give EKS service a name (instead of being auto-generated)

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

Say I have the following YAML representing a service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: arn:aws:acm:us-west-2:91371:certificate/0a389f-4086-4db6-9106-b587c90a3
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: http
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: "443"
  labels:
    app: main-api-prod
  name: main-api-prod
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
    - name: https
      protocol: TCP
      port: 443
      targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: main-api-prod
```

after I run:

```
kubectl apply -f <file>
```

I run:

```
kbc get svc -o json | grep hostname
```

and we see:

> "hostname":
>   "a392f200796b8b0279bdd390c-228227293.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com"

my question is - is there a way to tell `kubectl` to use my own id in the hostname? In other words, I would like to tell it to use "abc" instead of  "a392..", so it would be:

```
"abc-228227293.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com"
```

As an aside, if anyone knows what "228227293" represents, please lmk, I know that it is not our AWS accountid, that's for sure.

Answer (score 2):

When you create a service of type "load balancer", a new load balancer is created by your cloud provider (here aws). Load Balancer naming is of the responsibility of the cloud provider. I don't think you can tell amazon how to generate the load balancer name. And it may depends of the load balancer type - alb, internal alb, nlb, ....

But you can use "external-dns" (https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-dns). When configured for a dns providers - for exemple aws route53 - it can automatically creates dns aliases for your load balancer. But you won't be able to create name in amazonws.com domain ...